# How to capture data change (Insert DML) - Oracle 11g release 2 using python

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g

For some reason, oracle python have no CDC example python code if I search in google. If search for java, there are some open source tools like Streamsets.

Comment: What exactly do you want to capture?  The DML statement? The data?

Comment: Yes. Only DML statements.

Comment: The basic solution is to subclass the connection and do whatever logging you want, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tracing_sql.html